# query permissions for custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a custom token that contains a payload of *appid* to identify third party apps.

I'd like to verify reads/writes to my data such that:

1. the user is signed in (there is a valid *uid* / token)
2. the *appid* is registered in the `/apps` collection
3. the *uid* and *appid* are fields in the record and match the credentials
4. *(unrelated to this question, but to be complete)* this record matches the schema for the document.

## current best solution and remaining questions

This answer, that I eventually stumbled upon, is *pretty good*, but it might be improved.

The first thing I had to do was correctly identify the payload I was giving in the custom token -- because I am using a cloud service function to generate the payload (graphcool), my payload was `default: { appid }` instead of just `appid`. From there, just some rewording on the permissions was enough to succeessdully validate using the current rules I'd imagined:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /sampleData/{type}/{appName}/{record} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp(database) && ownsExisting() && appIdInExisting()
      allow write: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp(database) && ownsPayload() && appIdInPayload()
    }

    // functions
    function isSignedIn () {
        return request.auth != null
    }

    function isValidApp (database) {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/apps/$(request.auth.token.appid))
    }

    function ownsExisting () {
        return resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function ownsPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function appIdInExisting () {
        return resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }

    function appIdInPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }
  }
}
```

Someone could do better though.

1. is there any way to validate the *appid* without using an exists request (And without writing a *if-else if* chain)  -- like with an array directly in the rules perhaps?
2. how can I ensure that the *appid* specified in the payload matches the one I envisioned when I issued the service credentials to the client third-party-app?

## edit: original question

I thought I could get at least the first two myself:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /sampleData {
      allow read: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp() && ownsExisting() && appIdInExisting()
      allow write: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp() && ownsPayload() && appIdInPayload()
    }

    // functions
    function isSignedIn () {
        return request.auth != null
    }

    function isValidApp () {
        return get(path('apps')).data.child(request.auth.token.appid).exists()
    }

    function ownsExisting () {
        return resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function ownsPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function appIdInExisting () {
        return resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }

    function appIdInPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }
  }
}
```

`/apps` has 1 document called "sample-app-id" with *id* and *name* fields of "sample-app-id" ... but using this in my token does not work: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`

I am generating the token via this function on my server:

```
var FirebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin')
var serviceAccount = require('./firebase-service-credentials.json')
var claims = require('./custom-token-claims') // {appid: 'sample-app-id'}

let credential = FirebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
FirebaseAdmin.initializeApp({ credential })

const generateTokenWithPayload = async id => {
  try {
    const token = await FirebaseAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(id, claims)

    return { data: { token } }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error }
  }
}

module.exports = async event =>
  await generateTokenWithPayload(event.data.userIdentifier)
```

and before posting I am signing in -- this part I can verify seems to be working as I see the new, non-anonymous user in my **Authentication -> Users** tab in the firebase console:

```
— Feb 11, 2019 Feb 11, 2019 smaple-user-id
```

Here's essentially the client code:

```
await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCustomToken(token)
      .catch(console.error)
const db = await firebase.firestore()
db.collection(path + this.state.appName).add(payload)
```

I am posting a record with the schema `{app_id, app_name, date, metric, uid}` to **sampleData/metrics/sample-app-name/{auto-generated}**

### notes:

- the number of apps that are going to be registered is small -- it would probably make sense from a financial perspective to make this just a static array in the permissions file, if that is possible, rather than a *get* request.
- big improvement - I just noticed that `request.auth.token.appid` should be `request.auth.token.default.appid` because I was using `export default`instead of `modules.export`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is *pretty good*, but it might be improved.

The first thing I had to do was correctly identify the payload I was giving in the custom token -- because I am using a cloud service function to generate the payload (graphcool), my payload was `default: { appid }` instead of just `appid`. From there, just some rewording on the permissions was enough to succeessdully validate using the current rules I'd imagined:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /sampleData/{type}/{appName}/{record} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp(database) && ownsExisting() && appIdInExisting()
      allow write: if isSignedIn() && isValidApp(database) && ownsPayload() && appIdInPayload()
    }

    // functions
    function isSignedIn () {
        return request.auth != null
    }

    function isValidApp (database) {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/apps/$(request.auth.token.appid))
    }

    function ownsExisting () {
        return resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function ownsPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }

    function appIdInExisting () {
        return resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }

    function appIdInPayload () {
        return request.resource.data.app_id == request.auth.token.appid
    }
  }
}
```

Someone could do better though.

1. is there any way to validate the *appid* without using an exists request (And without writing a *if-else if* chain)  -- like with an array directly in the rules perhaps?
2. how can I ensure that the *appid* specified in the payload matches the one I envisioned when I issued the service credentials to the client third-party-app?